NextJS 15.0.2 - Failed to compile
I upgraded my nextJS website to 15.0.2 but I get this error :
Creating an optimized production build ...
Failed to compile.

./src/app/[locale]/path/file.module.scss
_0_0.call$1 is not a function

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/[locale]/path/file.module.scss
./src/app/[locale]/path/file.tsx    

> Build failed because of webpack errors


Every packages have been updated.
I tried to delete .next and node_modules. Then reinstalling them, but I still get the same error.

I wonder if it is coming from SASS, but not sure of anything…
Thank you

This error (_0_0. call$1 is not a function) frequently arises from problems with Webpack and styles following significant updates. Make sure to verify the compatibility of your SASS-related packages with Next. js 15 when using SCSS modules.
Update sass and sass-loader to their latest versions by executing:
npm install sass@latest sass-loader@latest
After that, remove any cache by deleting. next and node_modules directories, and proceed to reinstall the dependencies using npm install. If you have custom Webpack configurations in your next. config. js file, try temporarily commenting them out and rebuilding the project to check if they are causing compatibility issues. If this guidance proves helpful, re-enable configurations one by one to pinpoint the issue.
You might want to consider reverting CSS-related dependencies (such as sass or postcss-loader) to their previous versions if recent updates have caused conflicts. You have the option to utilize npx npm-check-updates to identify any version discrepancies.
For the final test, you can disable CSS modules by simply renaming file. module. scss to file. scss and importing it globally in _app. tsx. If the problem is solved, it probably indicates a conflict in handling CSS modules. You may want to consider going back to Next. js 15. 0. 1 as an option to investigate any possible issues with the current version.
